# How to create custom calendar like this in ios

Tags: ios, calendar

I have tried it doing with different calendar libraries  out there.But its not working for me.

please suggest something to overcome this issue

The calendar View I want to show is given [here](http://lms.medtechindia.com/suthakar/calendar.png).

Comment: I think you omitted the URL. Also you have not given any idea of what language/technology you intend to use. Perhaps you want to revise your question.

Comment: if you have zero idea, how you can start to implement a complex interface, I friendly recommend you to not force to do that kind of job...

Comment: We can do that by using horizontal table view.....but I am not not sure my approach is correct or not

Comment: You say you have tried out different libraries but they are not working for you. Can you share the code you have tried and explain better what is not working. Then people can try and help you. At the moment this looks more like a job for a freelancer than Stack Overflow

Comment: In the libraries out there like Kal Calendar,ios calendar....they are showing the whole calendar....i just wanna show the header view on it.....I am not getting how to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made this sliding menu

https://github.com/bishalg/SliderMenu

Looks like it has exact slider menu as per your need.

Comment: Thanks....Bishal I think it will work for me...

Comment: @user2346769 : cool ... im really happy that my code is helpful to someone :) don't forget to mark my answer.